# How to find the number of subscribers in an ExactTarget list without looping through every subscriber?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, wsdl

I'm trying to find the total number of subscribers that are within a specific ExactTarget list. I have the ListID, and am successfully connecting to the list. Since the list has about 1 million subscribers, when I try to pull the subscribers with that ListID, it takes a **really** long time.

All I want is the *number* of subscribers. ***I don't need any information of theirs***, just the amount that is apart of the list. Here's the simple code below:

```
//Make new request for number of subscribers in "All Subscribers" list
RetrieveRequest listSubscriberRequest = new RetrieveRequest();
listSubscriberRequest.ObjectType = "ListSubscriber";
listSubscriberRequest.Properties = new String[] { "SubscriberKey", "Status" };

 // Setting up a simple filter to look at ListID
 SimpleFilterPart sf = new SimpleFilterPart();
 sf.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
 sf.Property = "ListID";
 sf.Value = new String[] { listId };

 listSubscriberRequest.Filter = sf;

 APIObject[] listSubscriberResults = null;
 String listSubscriberRequestId = null;
 String listSubscriberResponse = null;
 int totalSubscribers = 0;

 //Retrieve subscribers, add length of return to total every retrieve
 do
 {
     listSubscriberResponse = soapClient.Retrieve(listSubscriberRequest, out listSubscriberRequestId, out listSubscriberResults);
     totalSubscribers += listResults.Length;
 }
 while (listSubscriberResponse.Equals("MoreDataAvailable")); //Continue to loop until end of subscribers
```

I want to be able to get rid of that do while because it is taking 10+ min.

Comment: I edited to add "exacttarget" as most reading this may assume "list" means an Apex list.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the System DataViews turned on.  You can create a query activity that does the aggregation based on the list ID ([ListSubscribers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_listsubscribers/)).   When you want to get that information, you can execute the query definitions via the API and wait for it to complete ([Perform Query](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/performing_a_query_activity_using_the_soap_web_service_api/)) or schedule it depending on your data freshness needs.  Then query your DataExtension and filter by your list id.